# ngx-admin Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUubM.png)

How to solve the error when trying to use multiple languages
In ngx-admin or Angular projects, it is common to save translation texts as JSON files and place these files in a certain directory of the project. A common practice is to place translation files in a folder called i18n (Internationalization, Internationalization).

ngx-admin {{ 'TITLE' | translate }} error

html

```
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a (click)="toggleSidebar()" href="#" class="sidebar-toggle">
      <nb-icon icon="menu-2-outline"></nb-icon>
    </a>
    <a class="logo" href="#" (click)="navigateHome()">{{ "ABC" | translate }}<span></span></a>
  </div>
  <nb-select [selected]="currentTheme" (selectedChange)="changeTheme($event)" status="primary">
    <nb-option *ngFor="let theme of themes" [value]="theme.value"> {{ theme.name }}</nb-option>
  </nb-select>
</div>

<div class="header-container">
  <nb-actions size="small">

    <nb-action class="control-item">
      <nb-search type="rotate-layout"></nb-search>
    </nb-action>
    <nb-action class="control-item" icon="email-outline"></nb-action>
    <nb-action class="control-item" icon="bell-outline"></nb-action>
    <nb-action class="user-action" *nbIsGranted="['view', 'user']" >
      <nb-user [nbContextMenu]="userMenu"
               [onlyPicture]="userPictureOnly"
               [name]="user?.name"
               [picture]="user?.picture">
      </nb-user>
    </nb-action>
  </nb-actions>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NbMediaBreakpointsService, NbMenuService, NbSidebarService, NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme';

import { UserData } from '../../../@core/data/users';
import { LayoutService } from '../../../@core/utils';
import { map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { TranslateService as MyTranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  userPictureOnly: boolean = false;
  user: any;

  themes = [
    {
      value: 'default',
      name: 'Light',
    },
    {
      value: 'dark',
      name: 'Dark',
    },
    {
      value: 'cosmic',
      name: 'Cosmic',
    },
    {
      value: 'corporate',
      name: 'Corporate',
    },
  ];

  currentTheme = 'default';

  userMenu = [ { title: 'Profile' }, { title: 'Log out' } ];

  

  constructor(private sidebarService: NbSidebarService,
              private menuService: NbMenuService,
              private themeService: NbThemeService,
              private userService: UserData,
              private layoutService: LayoutService,
              private breakpointService: NbMediaBreakpointsService,
              private translate: MyTranslateService,) {

              translate.addLangs(['en', 'zh']);
              // 设置默认语言
              translate.setDefaultLang('zh');
              translate.use('zh');
              console.log(translate)
              
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentTheme = this.themeService.currentTheme;

    this.userService.getUsers()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((users: any) => this.user = users.nick);

    const { xl } = this.breakpointService.getBreakpointsMap();
    this.themeService.onMediaQueryChange()
      .pipe(
        map(([, currentBreakpoint]) => currentBreakpoint.width < xl),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe((isLessThanXl: boolean) => this.userPictureOnly = isLessThanXl);

    this.themeService.onThemeChange()
      .pipe(
        map(({ name }) => name),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe(themeName => this.currentTheme = themeName);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  changeTheme(themeName: string) {
    this.themeService.changeTheme(themeName);
  }

  toggleSidebar(): boolean {
    this.sidebarService.toggle(true, 'menu-sidebar');
    this.layoutService.changeLayoutSize();

    return false;
  }

  navigateHome() {
    this.menuService.navigateHome();
    return false;
  }

  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    // 切换语言
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Akveo. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 */
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule,HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {
  NbChatModule,
  NbDatepickerModule,
  NbDialogModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbToastrModule,
  NbWindowModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';


import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';


// 创建 TranslateLoader，用于加载语言文件
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  
  //console.log(new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'))
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
  //return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '.\\assets\\i18n\\', '.json');

}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NbChatModule.forRoot({
      messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
    }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

How to solve the error when trying to use multiple langua